Can I make Bibtex read aux files from a subfolder?
I'm experiencing a problem with bibtex where it only recognises citations if I use a simple file structure.
So if I have my files like this:
rootfolder/
    main.tex
    chapters/
        chapter1.tex
        chapter1.aux
    main.aux
    main.log
    main.pdf
    main.bbl

that is fine, but I would like my output files seperated from my actual .tex files.
So I want to do a structure like this:
rootfolder/
    main.tex
    chapters/
        chapter1.tex
    out/
        main.aux
        main.log
        main.pdf
        main.bbl
        chapters/
            chapter1.aux
            chapter1.log
            chapter1.bbl
        

Problem is that when I run bibtex, it keeps looking at "rootfolder/chapters" instead of "rootfolder/out/chapters". I gues it resolves the references from \input{} statements from the main.tex file instead of the main.aux file. It gives me errors like this:
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 24.1)
The top-level auxiliary file: out\main.aux
The style file: apacite.bst
I couldn't open auxiliary file chapters/intro.aux
---line 14 of file out\main.aux
: @input{chapters/intro.aux
:                           }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

I use pdflatex to render the latex. That works fine. Only all citations end op as "?" and there is no bibliography when I use the fancy file structure.
If I do it with the simple file structure, everything renders perfectly. So the question is purely organizatonal. How can I use the fancy file structure?

the bib file will be found in any directory in the BIBINPUTS path so can be anywhere on your system. but I would always advise against using --output-directory setting output to  a subdirectory complicates everything you move the output of tex for purely cosmetic reasons but then you need to configure everything: bibtex, biber, makeindex, .... to find the files that have been written to non standard places

welcome! you could look at mklatex, but, if you use it with a non-standard build directory, remember that it only hides complications from you. it doesn't change them. so when stuff breaks, it is still you that gets to keep the pieces.

Do yourself a favour and don't use an auxdir. If you really must use such a structure, copy all your files into a build folder, do the compilation there and copy the resulting .pdf back. That's essentially what tools like ltx2any do to avoid most of the compilations from auxdirs.
